# calculate percentage depending on 2 categories in dplyr pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following artificial data:

```
date value cat
2019-01-01  10  a
2019-01-01  22  a
2019-01-01  44  b
2019-02-01  8   c
2019-02-01  10  c
```

And would like to produce this result:

```
date value cat total_value percentage_of_total
2019-01-01  10  a   32  31.25000
2019-01-01  22  a   32  68.75000
2019-01-01  44  b   44  100.00000
2019-02-01  8   c   18  44.44444
2019-02-01  10  c   18  55.55556
```

which corresponds to the percentage depending on 2 categories. My possibly long wounded attempt can be found below. Is there an easier way to achieve this? Thanks.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

haves <- data.frame(

    date = c(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-02-01"), as.Date("2019-02-01"))
    , value = c(10, 22, 44, 8, 10)
    , cat = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c")
)

haves

sum_stats <- df %>%
    group_by(
        date
        , cat
    ) %>%
    summarise(
        total_value = sum(value)
    ) %>%
    ungroup()

wants <- df %>%
    inner_join(sum_stats, by = c("date" = "date", "cat" = "cat")) %>%
    mutate(
        percentage_of_total = value/total_value * 100
    )

wants
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it in a shorter way as

```
haves %>% 
  group_by(date, cat) %>% 
  mutate(
    total_value = sum(value),
    percentage_of_total = value/total_value * 100
    ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#   date       value cat   total_value percentage_of_total
#   <date>     <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>               <dbl>
# 1 2019-01-01    10 a              32                31.2
# 2 2019-01-01    22 a              32                68.8
# 3 2019-01-01    44 b              44               100  
# 4 2019-02-01     8 c              18                44.4
# 5 2019-02-01    10 c              18                55.6
```

Comment: no offence. well I though one could use some fancy cum function.